# Launch a nodejs server on AWS EC2 with SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I tried to configure server with https. On local server, the local private key and certificate works. The code is:

```
var https = require('https');
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

But when I purchased a SSL certificate and try to use it on the AWS server, it didn't work at all.

```
var https = require('https');
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/portal.crt'),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('./ssl/portal.ca-bundle')]
};
```

It always showed webpage is not available. I also tried to upload the server certificate to AWS configuration, still failed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs? Are you sure this isn't simply a Security Group or firewall issue?